# Gekko: Problem with the obtained solution

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to solve the following Optimal Control Problem in GEKKO:

[image: problem]

I know a priori that the path for `c` is:

[image]

where the parameter values are: r = 0.33, i = 0.5, K(0) = 10 and T = 10.

I wrote the following code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
nt = 101; m.time = np.linspace(0,10,nt)
r = 0.33
i = 0.5

# Variables
c = m.Var()
k = m.Var(value=10)
objective = m.Var()

rate = [-r*t/10 for t in range(0, 101)]
factor = m.exp(rate)

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)
disc = m.Param(value=factor)


# Equations
m.Equation(k.dt() == i*k - c)
m.Equation(objective.dt() == disc*m.log(c))
# Objective Function
m.Maximize(final*objective)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(m.time,c.value,'k:',LineWidth=2,label=r'$C$')
plt.plot(m.time,k.value,'b-',LineWidth=2,label=r'$K$')

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
```

The solved path for `c` and `k` is as shown below:
[image]

This clearly is not right because `c` should be increasing with time from just eye-balling the solution given before hand.

I'm not sure where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal control problem as it is currently written is unbounded. The value of `c` will go to infinity to maximize the function. I set an upper bound of `100` on `c` and the solver went to that bound. I reformulated the model to reflect the current problem statement. Here are a few suggestions:

1. Use the `m.integral()` function to make the model more readable.
2. Initialize `c` at a value other than `0` (default). You may also want to set a lower bound with `c>0.01` so that `m.log(c)` is not undefined if the solver tries a value `<0`.
3. Only use Gekko functions inside Gekko equations such as with `factor = m.exp(rate)`. Use `factor = np.exp(rate)` instead unless it is in a Gekko equation where it can be evaluated.
4. Include a plot of the exact solution so that you can compare the exact and numerical solution.
5. Use `m.options.NODES=3` with `c=m.MV()` and `c.STATUS=1` to increase the solution accuracy. The default is `m.options.NODES=2` that isn't as accurate.
6. You can free the initial condition with `m.free_initial(c)` to calculate the initial value of `c`.

[image: Unbounded Solution]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
nt = 101; m.time = np.linspace(0,10,nt)
r = 0.33
i = 0.5

# Variables
c = m.MV(4,lb=0.01,ub=100); c.STATUS=1
#m.free_initial(c)
k = m.Var(value=10)
objective = m.Var(0)
t = m.Param(m.time)
m.Equation(objective==m.exp(-r*t)*m.log(c))

# just to include on the plot
iobj = m.Intermediate(m.integral(objective))

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

# Equations
m.Equation(k.dt() == i*k - c)
# Objective Function
m.Maximize(final*m.integral(objective))

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,c.value,'k:',linewidth=2,label=r'$C_{gekko}$')
C_sol = r*10*np.exp((i-r)*m.time)/(1-np.exp(-r*10))
plt.plot(m.time,C_sol,'r--',linewidth=2,label=r'$C_{exact}$')
plt.ylabel('Value'); plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,k.value,'b-',linewidth=2,label=r'$K$')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,objective.value,'g:',linewidth=2,label=r'$obj$')
plt.plot(m.time,iobj.value,'k',linewidth=2,label=r'$\int obj$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Is there additional information that this problem is missing?

**Edit:** Added additional constraint `k>0`.

Added additional constraint as suggested in the comment. There is a small difference at the end from the exact solution because the last `c` value does not appear to influence the solution.

[image: Solution with constraint]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=True)
nt = 101; m.time = np.linspace(0,10,nt)
r = 0.33
i = 0.5

# Variables
c = m.MV(4,lb=0.001,ub=100); c.STATUS=1; c.DCOST=1e-6
m.free_initial(c)
k = m.Var(value=10,lb=0)
objective = m.Var(0)
t = m.Param(m.time)
m.Equation(objective==m.exp(-r*t)*m.log(c))

# just to include on the plot
iobj = m.Intermediate(m.integral(objective))

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

# Equations
m.Equation(k.dt() == i*k - c)
# Objective Function
m.Maximize(final*m.integral(objective))

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 3
m.solve()

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,c.value,'k:',linewidth=2,label=r'$C_{gekko}$')
C_sol = r*10*np.exp((i-r)*m.time)/(1-np.exp(-r*10))
plt.plot(m.time,C_sol,'r--',linewidth=2,label=r'$C_{exact}$')
plt.ylabel('Value'); plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,k.value,'b-',linewidth=2,label=r'$K$')
plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(m.time,objective.value,'g:',linewidth=2,label=r'$obj$')
plt.plot(m.time,iobj.value,'k',linewidth=2,label=r'$\int obj$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Comment: K >= 0 was missing. Added that to get the C_exact to match C_gekko. Thanks a ton John!